# how to combine gps and gyroscope or accelemeter in navigation of car

Tags: c++, navigation

as the top says, i am doing some work on navigation of car. up to now i have Readed some papers and Carried out some preliminary experiments.ex,sensors fusion and kalman filter or some other algorithms. then i want to complete a navigation system which assemble gyroscope or accelemeter(if any),but i don't have a good idea to finish it, especially fuzzy to understand the information about coordinate frame conversation, noise error compensation or correction, and also difficult to code in c/c++ by the end.so could you give me some idea about this.if a demo haved opensource code can be provieded, perfect to see it. forgiving me for my poor english, can you understand what i am saying?

Comment: Confusion with the physics can best be overcome by reading physics texts, and if you have questions asking the Physics stack exchange site.  Once you are firm in your understanding of what needs to be done it is easier to devise code to meet your needs.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. The current main proplem of me is feeling helpless to get a whole solution to solved it. may be i can't deeply understand the detail in the process. so i wish to have a demo or example application about it. you know that i will quickly get it by reading code if it's a good job. so in fact i want to study by the help of some project respected to a car navigation system. can you provid one?

Comment: This is just not answerable. I've seen demo's from TNO Automotive Engineering on this subject, and you'd need a PhD to understand them. OTOH, considering that GPS tells you nothing about the heading and a gyroscope only does that, combining those two is trivial. BTW there's no "C/C++" language.

Comment: To MSalters：As I known, It's typical method to combine gps and sensors like gyroscope and accelemeter in navigation system. when the car in channel or somewhere has shortage gps singal, a gyroscope is well to position the car supported by the accelemeter or odometer. they are joined to make precies position. why you say that is trivial? BTW you are humorous.